# Check duplicate key in database using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, duplicates

> I design two method getRandomKey and checkduplicatekey and i need to
>   know the duplicate key exist in database or not.If duplicate key exist
>   then call generateRandomKey method again.In short need Unique key when
>   calling generateRandomkey() method.

```
String generateRandomKey() {
        int count = INT_TEN;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        while (count-- != 0) {
            int character = (int) (Math.random() * ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
            builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
        }
        String randomkey = builder.toString();
        boolean status = checkDuplicateRandomkey(randomkey);
        if (status==false) {


        }
        return randomkey;
    }


boolean checkDuplicateRandomkey(String randomkey){
        Boolean flag = false;
                Transaction transaction;
                Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
                        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("randomKey", randomkey));
                        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
                    int count = ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
                        transaction.commit();
                       if(count != 0){
                           System.out.println("present");
                           String randomKey=generateRandomKey();
                       }
                       else{
                           System.out.println("absent");
                           flag=false;
                       }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    logger.error("Exception : ", exception);
                } finally {
                    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
                }
                return flag;
```

Comment: check for hash algorithms  try to implement if you want to understand the issue or use a library for quick solution.

Comment: please provide solution for the existing code.

Comment: In the entity classes, for the specific ID, you need to declare the sequence generator method. 
Also you can specify the sequence generator at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, assuming you're using JPA, I would strongly suggest that you use a javax.persistence.GeneratedValue value like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

If you really want to use a UID, I would do it like this, there is no need to check it will be unique:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").substring(0, 20)
```

The 0,20 is if you want to cut it down, it will generate a string like :

```
1066c717c8154ab5aeab
```